# Pass parameters as unpacked array

Tags: python

I came across [a blog post](http://dataconomy.com/2015/04/implementing-the-five-most-popular-similarity-measures-in-python/) with the following function call:

```
intersection_cardinality = len(set.intersection(*[x, y]))
```

Is there any benefit in passing parameters as an unpacked array created just for that, instead of simply calling `set.intersection(x, y)`?

The blog post was written in python2, but the question goes for 3 as well.

Comment: In that case, this is nothing but syntactic sugar. I'm not even sure it is so sweet.

Comment: `set.intersection(*[x, y])` is an overcomplicated way of writing the simple expression `x & y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you provided, there is no real point in using this syntax.

There are cases though where creating an array or tuple to unpack it can be useful.

```
# Python3

def print_n_times(n, string):
    # Instead of doing a loop we unpack an array of length n
    print(*n*(string,), sep='\n')
```

Comment: It's also useful to unpack generators and generator expressions to pass to a variadic function like `print` or `zip`.